# definition of basis matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

my linear algebra textbook

there is sentence

A change of basis matrix from one orthonormal basis to another orthonomal basis in a complex vector space is unitary

in this sentence

I have a question

what is a 'basis matrix' ?

Comment: It is not "change of 'basis matrix'". Its name is "change-of-basis matrix".

Comment: then what is mean of "change -of-basis matrix'?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you read it as this:

A change of "basis matrix"...

That is not how you should read it. Instead, it reads:

A "change-of-basis matrix"...

Its definition is as follows:

A change-of-basis matrix from one ordered basis $\{\vec v_1,\vec v_2,\dots,\vec v_n\}$ to another ordered basis $\{\vec w_1,\vec w_2,\dots,\vec w_n\}$ is the $n\times n$ square matrix $B=[b_{ij}]$ whose entries satisfy the equations $$\vec v_j=\sum_{i=1}^nb_{ij}\vec w_i$$ for each $j=1,2,\dots,n$.